# How to initiate props when rendering Component?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a Login Component where I want the user to choose Service from a Service Catalogue. The Picker gets and sets values to redux:

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.props.service.id}
  onValueChange={itemValue => this.props.setServiceType(itemValue)}>
  {service_catalogue.map(service =>
      <Picker.Item key={service.id} label={service.id} value={service.id} />
  )}
</Picker>
```

But I don't know how to properly set the initial value. I set the default value in componentDidMount (the first item in the Catalogue), but I think componentDidMount is trigged on update? Is there a lifecycle function that is only triggered on rendering Component in React Native?

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.setServiceType(service_catalogue[0].id)
}
```

So the problem that I'm facing is that even though the user might choose "Instructor" the service becomes service_catalogue[0] = "Cleaner". And if I don't setServiceType on componentDidMount no Picker appears, as this.props.service.id doesn't exist.

Comment: hi, did you tried "shouldComponentUpdate()" lifecycle method of that component ? This method fired at right before of every component re-render.

Comment: The thing is I only want to run my function once, before rendering. I tried putting it in the constructor but the constructor runs on re-render at times too.

Comment: I now have my "initator" in componentDidMount: `!this.props.serviceType && this.props.setServiceType(service_catalogue[0].id)`, i.e. it will only be run if serviceType is not set. Maybe not the best solution but does the trick!

Comment: If you set serviceType with redux, it should already have an initial state. "this.props.serviceType" is mapped from redux state, right? So why don't you just set the initial redux state in your reducer?

Comment: @negative_zero Say for example that I have 100 services in my service catalogue, and they are divided into four categories depending on what user group you belong to. Then there are four different inital staets and it just seems easier to set the inital state in the component rather than in redux but maybe it's the wrong approach?

Comment: @howtopythonpls Not wrong but it can be done in redux side which seems more clear to me. If catalogue is dependent on user group then you should be sure to update it when user group state is updated. I'm not a redux expert but I know that it can be done with [redux-thunk's composition feature](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#composition)

Answer (score 1):

You can set default value for the props on the following way:

```
...
YourComponent.propTypes = {
  myState: PropTypes.string,
}

YourComponent.defaultProps = {
  myState: 'default value',
};

const mapStateToProps = state = ({
  myState: state.myState,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent);
```

> More info: https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#default-prop-values

Comment: I should have been clearer, it's redux props. And this is a react-native question, not React.

Comment: I'm not familiar with react-native, but as redux maps the state into the props of the component, you can still use the `defaultProps`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I see how I described my problem poorly now. It is actually the global state that I want to initiate on component load (once), rather than the props of the component. The component gets its props from the state automatically but as I don't want the global state to have a inital state I need to initate it in the Component (call action setProvider()). I need to do this so I am certain this is set before navigating to next view.

Comment: Okay, so as I understand you want to update the state before rendering the component right? And also without setting initial state. In that case I would say you should update the state in the `constructor()` or the `componentDidMount()` method and blocking the rendering until you update the state. For example adding a new state variable like `isLoading` and updating its value based on the update state.